# A classy wine collection - Construction vs. Initialization

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, constructor

The following is for a chapter exercise in *C++ Primer Plus, 6/e* by Stephen Prata, for the first part of Chapter 14 which deals with code reuse through composition. The problem is to implement a `Wine` class (for modelling a wine collection) which contains a `std::string` (the wine name), an `int` and a `Pair` of `std::valarray`s to hold the vintages and bottles held of each. (`Pair` is a template class provided by the author.)

My question is whether I've got a good solution for the `Wine` constructors, or if I should be setting up my `Pair` in the initializer list (and what that would look like.)

Here's my header…

```
/**
* @file     winec.h
* @brief    Wine class with containment
*/

#ifndef WINEC_H_
#define WINEC_H_

#include <string>
#include <valarray>
#include "pair.h"

typedef std::valarray<int> ArrayInt;
typedef Pair<ArrayInt, ArrayInt> PairArray;

class Wine
{
private:
    std::string mLabel;
    PairArray holdings;
    int yearsHeld;

public:
    Wine();
    Wine(const char *l, int y);
    Wine(const char *l, int y, const int yrs[], const int bot[]);

    void getBottles();
    std::string & label();
    int sum() const;
    void show() const;
};

#endif
```

… and my implementation…

```
/**
* @file     winec.cpp
* @brief    Wine class with containment
*/

#include "winec.h"

Wine::Wine()
    : mLabel("Unnamed"), yearsHeld(0)
{
    holdings.first() = ArrayInt(0);
    holdings.second() = ArrayInt(0);
};


Wine::Wine(const char *l, int y)
    : mLabel(l), yearsHeld(y)
{
    holdings.first() = ArrayInt(0, y);
    holdings.second() = ArrayInt(0, y);
}


Wine::Wine(const char *l, int y, const int yrs[], const int bot[])
    : mLabel(l), yearsHeld(y)
{
    holdings.first() = ArrayInt(y);
    holdings.second() = ArrayInt(y);

    for (int i = 0; i < yearsHeld; i++)
    {
        holdings.first()[i] = yrs[i];
        holdings.second()[i] = bot[i];
    }
}


std::string & Wine::label()
{
    return mLabel;
}


void Wine::show() const
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cout << "Wine: " << mLabel << endl;
    cout << "\tYear\tBottles\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < yearsHeld; i++)
    {
        cout << "\t" << holdings.first()[i];
        cout << "\t" << holdings.second()[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void Wine::getBottles()
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;

    cout << "Enter holdings for " << yearsHeld << " years.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < yearsHeld; i++)
    {
        cout << "Year: ";
        cin >> holdings.first()[i];
        cout << "Bottles: ";
        cin >> holdings.second()[i];
    }
}


int Wine::sum() const
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < yearsHeld; i++)
    {
        sum += holdings.second()[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

… along with the author's `Pair<>` template:

> ```
> /**
> * @file       pair.h
> * @brief  Defining & using a Pair template
> */
>
> #ifndef PAIR_H_
> #define PAIR_H_
>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
>
> template <class T1, class T2>
> class Pair
> {
> private:
>   T1 a;
>   T2 b;
>
> public:
>   T1 & first();
>   T2 & second();
>   T1 first() const { return a; }
>   T2 second() const { return b; }
>   Pair(const T1 &aval, const T2 &bval) : a(aval), b(bval) {}
>   Pair() {}
> };
>
>
> template <class T1, class T2>
> T1 & Pair<T1, T2>::first()
> {
>   return a;
> }
>
>
> template <class T1, class T2>
> T2 & Pair<T1, T2>::second()
> {
>   return b;
> }
>
> #endif
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Code Review

Just wondering if there is an EC library inside windows.
Best to be descriptive and long winded here.

```
#ifndef WINEC_H_
#define WINEC_H_
```

Also you may want to put all your code inside a namespace.

In this scheme were you access the year and count you have to perform two array lookups. Not a big deal. But to me the logic seems the wrong way around.

```
typedef std::valarray<int> ArrayInt;
typedef Pair<ArrayInt, ArrayInt> PairArray;
```

I would have done this:

```
typedef Pair<int, int>         WineInfo;
typedef std::vector<WineInfo>  PairArray;
```

Now when you have the year (vintage) you have the count in the same object (better spacial locality).

Is this not simply the size of `holdings`?

```
    int yearsHeld;
```

I would not have a default constructor.
Is there a need to create an special "unnamed" object?

Sure you can pass by C-String

```
Wine::Wine(const char *l, int y)
```

But I usually make this a `std::string const&` then it can be used with strings and with C-Strings (the string is dynamically constructed in place). If you are worried about the copy you can always add a constructor that takes the parameter by r-value reference so it is moved into the object.

I don;t like passing `y` the number of years held. Then just creating a set of unitialized values. The year `0` is not really a valid value.

```
Wine::Wine(const char *l, int y)
```

What you could do is allow a list initializer. This takes a list of `WineInfo` that allows you to initialize the object.

```
Wine  myWine("Flore de Sole", {{2014,15},{2013,8},{2012,3},
                                {2011,1},{2010,1},{2009,1}}
            );
```

OK. So you try. But this is a very dangerous interface. There is no way to guarantee that the `yrs` array and the `bot` array are at least `y` size.

```
Wine::Wine(const char *l, int y, const int yrs[], const int bot[])
    : mLabel(l), yearsHeld(y)
```

You should pass references to objects of known size. You could pass a reference to an array of length `y`

```
template<int y>
Wine::Wine(const char *l, const int (yrs&)[y], const int (bot&)[y])
    : mLabel(l), yearsHeld(y)
```

Always hat getters. They break encapsulation.

```
std::string & Wine::label()
{
    return mLabel;
}
```

Also note you are returning a non cost reference. So the caller can alter the label dynamically.

```
w.label() = "Plop";
```

Sure. Always good to have a print function. But rather than fix it with `std::cout` pass the stream as a parameter. The default can always be `std::cout`

```
void Wine::show() const
```

I would write as

```
void Wine::show(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const
```

Always prefer `\n` over `std::endl`

```
    cout << "Wine: " << mLabel << endl;
```

The difference is that `std::endl` will also flush the buffer. This makes using streams very in-effecient. You practically never need to flush the buffer manually.

Rather than using a manual loop. Prefer to use an algorithm

```
    for (int i = 0; i < yearsHeld; i++)
    {
        sum += holdings.second()[i];
    }
```

Simpler to write:

```
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(holdings), std::end(holdings));
```

No need to copy if you just need a reference.

```
  T1 first() const { return a; }
  T2 second() const { return b; }
```

Just return by const reference. Then it can be used without having a copy made.

```
  T1 const& first() const { return a; }
  T2 const& second() const { return b; }
```

Comment: I admit the Pair-of-valarrays had been bugging me as well; inverting it makes more sense and lets me use an initializer as well: `holdings(VintageList(WineInfo(0,0), y))`. My compiler doesn't like `Wine::Wine(const char *l, const int (yrs&)[y], const int (bot&)[y])` and I can't get `std::accumulate()` to work with `Pair<>` but those are peripheral to the exercise, and I suppose I can always post them on SO. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to ask: what did you mean by "EC library?"

Comment: Half a joke: But all windows header files have `WIN` as the prefix,. If there was a windows library called `EC`. Then the header to this library would be `WINEC`